# Cropping sf map in R

Tags: r, sf

I'm trying to plot all rivers in the Iberian Peninsula as can be seen on the image, but the shapefile includes the Canary Islands and info about Northern Africa. To plot it I used:

```
library(sf)
library(tidyverse)
rios <- st_read("/Users/JMFR/Downloads/BCN500/BCN500_0301L_HIDROGRAFIA.shp")
ggplot() +
  borders("world", c("spain", "portugal"), fill = "lightsteelblue") +
  geom_sf(data = rios)
```

The shape file can be downloaded from https://www.dropbox.com/s/gqoz9xppf4bjwt2/bcn500_0301l_hidrografia.shp?dl=0

[image: What I get]
I can delete all North Africa info with

```
rios <- rios %>%
  drop_na()
```

I've tried to use

```
rios <- st_crop(rios, c(xmin= -9.80, ymin = 27.68933, xmax = 4.837648, ymax = 35.95))
```

But what I got was just a few rivers from North Africa, as the plot shows.

[image: screenshot]

But I don't know how to delete all info from Canary Islands. My final goal is this plot north of lat. 35.95 and up to long -9.80 so I can get something as this image it is the same that from the red square).

[image: screenshot]

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Your cropping extent, specifically `ymin` and `ymax` is wrong. In the code you showed you only cropped to the African part. This should crop to the Iberian Peninsula:

```
rios <- st_crop(rios, c(xmin= -9.80, ymin = 36, xmax = 4.837648, ymax = 44))
```

Answer (score 2):

Cropping, as you've seen, cuts the features to a square bounding box; `st_intersection` makes a clip along the boundary of the clipping layer, in your case, I would filter out the islands and then intersect:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(raster)
library(sf)
library(dplyr)
esp = getData(country = "ESP", level = 1)
esp = esp %>% st_as_sf() %>% filter(!NAME_1 %in% c("Islas Canarias", "Islas Baleares"))
rios = st_read("/Users/JMFR/Downloads/BCN500/BCN500_0301L_HIDROGRAFIA.shp")
rios = st_intersection(rios, esp)
```

Comment: If one is cropping out of a very large or complex layer, it can speed things up to run `crop()` first and then intersect the result - but the size disparity has to be pretty massive for it to matter, e.g. a village's worth of property boundaries from a national coverage.